# Which type of termite control is the most efficient in term of price in my case

Tags: pest-control, contractors

Which type of termite control is the most efficient in term of price in my case?

All the wood flooring and pillar had termite colony in my case...

Comment: Since we can't see how extensive the colony is and the amount of damage, I don't think anyone would be able to give you sound advice over the internet.  I would instead consult a couple of local extermination companies and have them give you pro's/con's for different treatment options.

Answer (score 4):

The most cost-effective methods of termite control, in descending order:

1. Live where it's too cold for termites - $
2. Treat the soil around the perimeter of your house with termiticide once every 5-10 years - $
3. Build a physical termite barrier around your house out of metal, fine sand, cementboard, or some other material that termites can't eat or pass through, leaving inspection strips along the perimeter of the foundation - $
4. Build the structure and finish materials of your house out of non-wood materials - $$$

...

579. Wait until your house has a major termite infestation and needs to be fumigated and major structural and finish materials replaced - $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

Answer (score 0):

Millions of dollars are unnecessarily spent here

If you can locate a good termite professional which has good construction knowledge, the source of the termite activity can be located and treated. Be for I was in pest control (23 years) I poured concrete slabs for 5 years. So I saw the situations where wood would be left in the concrete slabs. What a valuable tool construction turned out to be for me now.

Have you seen a swarm castle or swarmers exiting from a particular area? Several photos of the damaged areas would be helpful. Pier and beam, floating slab, or monolithic slab? Is the slab all one level with no step ups? Is there any plumbing within 5 feet of the damaged area? Is it exterior wall? Can you see your foundation all along the outside?

These are all critical questions and can cost or save you thousands of dollars. A lot of termite companies will use the lack of knowledge to extract dollars from you. A good spot treatment may only run you $300-$500.

Most structures can be spot treated if a good termiticide is used. Unfortunately, even some of the local and national companies use the cheaper termiticides which the treatments are only about 70% effective. Use cheap tools and you get cheap results.

In the last 15 years I have only had to fully treat 2 homes due only to the fact that the termites were entering them from all sides. Out of the hundreds of spot treatments I have done in the last 15 years, I have yet to have a re-treatment using the good termiticides. The problem is that most companies won't warranty their work if you don't treat the whole structure. But I do warranty my spot treatments and so do some other companies.

Good luck